# The effect of changing sample sizes on outliers

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I know that the size of a sample is inversely proportional to the width of a confidence interval, and that outliers tend to increase the width of the interval as well. So that must mean that increasing the sample size reduces the effect of outliers on a confidence interval, and decreasing the sample size amplifies the effect, correct?

How can I show this using formulae instead of words for, say a confidence interval for a one-sample $z$-test?

Also as a side note, does changing the sample size change how outliers affect the $p$-value of a hypothesis test? I'm inclined to say yes, but I'm not sure how to justify that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The width of a z CI for normal $\mu$ when $\sigma$ is known is
inversely proportional to $\sqrt{n},$ not $n.$ Because $\sigma$ is known,
the sample SD $S$ plays no role in the width of the CI. [If you are
talking about unknown $\sigma$ and t CI's, then the width depends
on $n$, the appropriate quantile of t for df $n-1$, and the size of the sample
SD (a random variable).]

(2) If data are normal, there may be outliers. Normal tails
go out to $\pm \infty$ even though the probability of extreme
values beyond $\mu \pm 3\sigma$ are rare. After a certain point, as the sample size
increases, so does the likelihood of getting an outlier.
(Boxplots are not really intended for use with samples with very small $n$, and so I'm
talking about $n \ge 15$ or so. The definition of 'quartile' is a bit sketchy in a
sample of size 5, or 11.)

(3) I do not know of any 'formula' that directly links (1) and (2), mostly
because I know of no formula for the numbers of outliers. I have
seen simulation studies that show the results, but outliers
depend on the quartiles and their distributions with increasing $n$
are a bit messy.

(4) Here are simulations that estimate the average numbers of outliers per sample
in normal samples of various sizes $n = 20$, $n = 50,$ and $n = 100$. By averaging
outliers in many samples of each size, one can approximate the
expected number of outliers. Results for expected numbers
of outliers per sample are about 0.33, 0.58, and 0.92, respectively.

While many extreme outliers may be a signal that a sample is not
from a normal distribution, we see from these simulations that there is nothing 'abnormal' about getting some outliers in a normal
sample. About a quarter of samples of size 20 have them and 
a normal sample of size 100 is more likely to have some outliers than not.
The values from t tables that are used to make t CIs (when $\sigma$
is estimated by $S$) allow for the effect of such inherently normal outliers.

```
m = 10^5;  n = 20; nr.out = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  nr.out[i] = length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(n))$out)}
mean(nr.out)
## 0.33063
mean(nr.out > 0)
## 0.23268

m = 10^5;  n = 50; nr.out = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  nr.out[i] = length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(n))$out)}
mean(nr.out)
## 0.57625

m = 10^5;  n = 100; nr.out = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  nr.out[i] = length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(n))$out)}
mean(nr.out)
## 0.91808
mean(nr.out > 0)
## 0.51877
```

*Notes:* Without loss of generality, it is OK
to use standard normal populations.
The simulations use $m = 10^5$ samples of each size. If you are
familiar with R statistical software, you can do your own simulations
for other values of $n$.

Comment: So having larger sample sizes increases the likelihood of having more outliers? But doesn't that mean that having more outliers would widen a CI, which doesn't make sense because larger sample sizes make the interval narrower? Sorry if I'm misinterpreting your answer.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. More generally, the connection between the width of CIs and the number of outliers as $n$ increases is not simple or easy to understand.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. For example, what if there was a sample $n$ that had one known outlier, and I conducted the hypothesis test anyway. If I redid the test with $2n$ and kept every other parameter the same so that there's still only that one outlier, does that mean the CI for the first test would be narrower than the CI for the second test?

Comment: That's one way to look at it. More generally, the connection between the width of CIs and the number of outliers as $n$ increases is not simple or easy to understand. Also, simulation results for outliers are dependent on the 'outlier rule'. (I used the usual rule that fences are 1.5IQR beyond the quartiles. There is some evidence that number of outliers is more stable as a function of $n$ if you use 2.25IQR. But with any rule outliers increase as $n \rightarrow \infty$.)

Comment: If you pick individual particular cases, the discussion could go on forever. You can't guarantee what outliers you might get with an additional $n$ observations. I'm talking about general trends on average as $n$ increases.

Comment: Right, I think I understand what you're saying: as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the number of outliers increases. But my original question was asking whether, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the impact of an outlier on a CI is increased or reduced, assuming there are no other parameter changes other than $n$. Sorry if I wasn't being clear.

Comment: In view of apparent misunderstandings in your earlier comments, I have added a few sentences to my Answer. Perhaps if you return to it after some reflection, you will get a clearer picture of the natural (even if perhaps somewhat unintuitive) role of outliers in normal samples.